# which plugin or extension to jump into declaration of function by mouse in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The feature exists in Sublime.

I want the same in VS Code: If i want to jump to declaration of the function, i hover onto the function and it gives me option to go to that page where it's already defined.

Comment: Depends of which computer language you want that feature.
There are different plugins to solve that issue for different computer languags.

Comment: Also, some plugins require correct path settings in project configuration, so that the language parser plugin knows where to look for other project files and third-party libraries.